# Adding custom link and page in my account page

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: Warranty link added in my account]

[image: when clicked on link error is shown]

how can a link with a workable page be created in the my account menu????

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a module for that.
Your module must contain at least a controller with an action a layout file and a helper (used for translation).
You should find enough tutorials on the web about this.
Now...your layout file must contain this in order to add a link in the customer account menu:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="[module]"><name>[module]</name><path>[module][controller]/[action]</path><label>Menu label</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

and your controller action should look something like this:

```
public function someAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```